# How to find files and act on them (find + exec)

Tags: find, path, recursive, exec

I have downloaded about 3200 websites to the depth 2. So now I have one master folder (abc) that contains many folders, containing files for each website. So my folder abc contains 3200 folders and each folder contains other folders that contains files with text from the websites. I have also a script that can edit text in each file. It is stored in file named lynx.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
fileA=$1
while IFS= read -r lineA
do
LTRA=$(echo "${lineA:0:1}")
catA=$(lynx -dump -nonumbers -nomargins -nolist -noprint -width 1000 -assume_charset=utf-8 $2/*.* )
editA=$(echo "$catA" | sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g')
editB=$(echo "$editA" | sed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g')
editC=$(echo "$editB" | sed '/^http/ d' )
editD=$(echo "$editC" | sed '/^IFRAME/ d' )
editE=$(echo "$editD" | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' )
editF=$(echo "$editE" | sed -r 's/[^aáäbcčdďdzdžeéfghchiíjklĺľmnňoópqrŕsštťuúvwxyýzžAÁÄBCČDĎDZDŽEÉFGHCHIÍJKLĹĽMNŇOÓPQRŔSŠTŤUÚVWXYÝZŽ][^aáäbcčdďdzdžeéfghchiíjklĺľmnňoópqrŕsštťuúvwxyýzžAÁÄBCČDĎDZDŽEÉFGHCHIÍJKLĹĽMNŇOÓPQRŔSŠTŤUÚVWXYÝZŽ]+//g' )
editG=$(echo "$editF" | sed s'/[^aáäbcčdďdzdžeéfghchiíjklĺľmnňoópqrŕsštťuúvwxyýzžAÁÄBCČDĎDZDŽEÉFGHCHIÍJKLĹĽMNŇOÓPQRŔSŠTŤUÚVWXYÝZŽ]$//')
editH=$(echo "$editG" | sed s'/^[^aáäbcčdďdzdžeéfghchiíjklĺľmnňoópqrŕsštťuúvwxyýzžAÁÄBCČDĎDZDŽEÉFGHCHIÍJKLĹĽMNŇOÓPQRŔSŠTŤUÚVWXYÝZŽ]//')
editI=$(echo "$editH" | sed 's/ .*//')
editJ=$(echo "$editI" | sed '/^$/d' )
echo "$editJ" > $2/"blaaa"_lynx.txt
echo "$lineA"
done <"$fileA"
```

It makes text in each file to be edited - every word is on the new line. I have used this script many times before but I use it with file input.txt which contains names of all websites that i have.

Now I am trying to edit all folders in my abc folder at once. I have tried to use somtehing like this:

```
find /home/student/eny/abc -exec lynx.sh {} \;
find /home/student/eny/abc/* -iname -exec ./lynx.sh input.txt {} \;
```

and many others. I can not find a solution for this.

In **input.txt** there are names of sites for example: *kosice.sk bratislava.sk presov.sk* every name of the site is on a new line and they are in aplhabet order. And they are also as names of dir of the first level.

Comment: If I understood your question right, you can first search files that you need for something, and store them into a temp file. Then you can use `xargs`, something like `cat list_of_files.txt | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo command1 %;'`. Ofc this can be done in more elegant way.

Comment: `find /home/student/eny/abc -exec lynx.sh {} \;` is just fine except you should add -type f to find only files not dirs. Not clear what you think is wrong/does not work?

Comment: You should add a parameter to `-iname` and you should try to used `execplus` (`-exec ... {} +`) if there are many files to work on.

Comment: @LevBystritskiy I can not store files in a temp file because it is too many files. As I mentioned before I have downloaded about 3200 webpages to the depth 2. So ist lots of files. I have to work with all files from all webpages.

Comment: @Tagwint It does not work for all files in all folders. It only edits maybe first folder to the depth 1 and other files and other folders (from 3200 amount) and are untouched.

Comment: @schily can you please specify how to use execplus for my case?

Comment: find /home/student/eny/abc -type f 
will find **every** file down the dir tree. You can check it with *echo*  
find /home/student/eny/abc -type f -exec echo {} \;  Likewise it will call your lynx.sh script for every file. You should elaborate 'Does not work'

Comment: @Tagwint I have tried to use -type f as you recomended and it works fine untill I have tried to use it with my lynx. It writes **find: `.lynx.sh': No such file or directory**
I have tried to write it like: 
'find /home/student/eny/bbb -type f -exec .lynx.sh input.txt {} \;'
'find /home/student/eny/bbb -type f -exec lynx.sh input.txt {} \;'
'find /home/student/eny/bbb -type f -exec lynx.sh {} \;'

Comment: I'd better put it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final version of your command

`find /home/student/eny/abc -type f -exec ./lynx.sh {} \;`

Points to note:

1. `-type f` finds files only
2. you should specify path to your script `./` (dot slash) means current dir, you may want to specify the full path
3. lynx.sh should have executable bit set file mode 0755 would be fine

Comment: Lynx.sh is in the current dir so probably path will not be needed (I hope so). 

Well, this is the first time it does somenthing different than usually. This is what it does after your new command:

`./lynx.sh: line 17: /bla_lynx.txt: Permission denied
#!/bin/bash
./lynx.sh: line 17: /bla_lynx.txt: Permission denied
fileA=$1
./lynx.sh: line 17: /bla_lynx.txt: Permission denied
while IFS= read -r lineA
./lynx.sh: line 17: /bla_lynx.txt: Permission denied
do`
Actually it re-writes everything in my lynx.sh and started re-writing everything else what find has found.

Comment: lynx.sh expects 2 parameters, first find command provides only one, so the $2 placeholder in your script is empty which results in attempt to write to /blalynx.txt file. That is aboslute path where non-root user does not have permition to write. I did not revise the correctness of the script, assuming it's fine and you only need help with find command. I suggest you first test your script w/o find iterations, start it manually with an arbitrary file that find would find. Once being sure it works with one file, apply your find commands.

Comment: I have tested this script before and it worked fine. Also before you helped me, some of my tries to write path worked in a way that it creates one file bla_lynx.sh correctly but not for all files, so I thought path is the problem.

Comment: I have tested it once again on one file and it creates bla_lynx.sh and it was perfect, but when I add find, it stopped working and do what I said before.
So on the same file it works without find and when I add find it shows "Permission denied" @Tagwint

Comment: Please show the exact command you tested it so we can find out the differesnce from find approach

Comment: It was  `./lynx.sh input.txt /home/student/eny/abc/111` In folder 111 there is about 20 files and it creates one bla_lynx.sh with requested content. @Tagwint

Comment: What does input.txt looks like please, are the names of downloaded sites the same as names of dir of the 1st level? Please show some lines of input.txt

Comment: Exactly. There are names of sites for example: _kosice.sk bratislava.sk presov.sk_ every name of the site is on a new line and they are in aplhabet order. And they are also as names of dir of the first level.  @Tagwin

Comment: OK. Here's what we have http://hastebin.com/qagabucago.txt
Please confirm or modify.
Then please describe  expected result as precise as you can.

Comment: Little edit http://hastebin.com/ofapoguvow.avrasm Expected result of lynx.sh is to edit e.g index.html or another .txt file so that in the output bla_lynx.txt will be every single word on a new line and parts of code such as `<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> ` will be erased. Something like this: http://hastebin.com/guquxizoge.xml @Tagwin

Comment: Do you  want one single bla_lynx.txt keepping all the words from all sites, or every dir to have its own  bla_lynx.txt with results from that site only?

Comment: Well, it will be better if every dir has its own bla_lynx.txt.@Tagwint

Comment: Please check this http://hastebin.com/deyisebari.sh
 That is simplified version of lynx.sh that does not require  any parameters. You can name it say lynx2.sh and give it a try.
See explanatory comments inside.

Comment: Wow! That works fine unless there is txt file that contains only text without those typical html signs, only pure text. Then it says:` Alert!: Unable to access document. lynx: Can't access startfile` and repeats attempts. And also if I want to use lynx on more than depth 1, lets say up to 5, why does it stores separates *_blaa_lynx.txt files? Can it be together? @Tagwin